# how delete space in blank only between " " with bash

Tags: regex, awk, sed

txt with this format

```
"service blabla 1"                   5.456
"service blabla 2"                   456
```

i need remove space in blank only between " "

```
"serviceblabla1"                   5.456
"serviceblabla2"                   456
```

i have this command

> sed 's/ //g'

result:

```
"serviceblabla2"456
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `perl` here:

```sh
perl -i -pe 's{"[^"]*"}{$&=~s|\s+||gr}ge' file
```

Note that `-i` will replace the text inline.

The `"[^"]*"` pattern will match any substrings in between the closest double quotation marks and `$&=~s|\s+||gr` willl remove all chunks of one or more whitespace chars inside the matches only.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/bbZRgR):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='"service blabla 1"                   5.456
"service blabla 2"                   456'
perl -pe 's{"[^"]*"}{$&=~s|\s+||gr}ge' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
"serviceblabla1"                   5.456
"serviceblabla2"                   456
```

Answer (score 6):

In GNU `awk` with shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",RT);ORS=RT} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Setting RS as `"[^"]*"` to get values from `"` till next occurrence of `"`. Then removing spaces in its value to match OP's requirement. Finally printing the line.

Above code will print data on terminal, in case you want to inplace save into Input_file, then try following command.

```
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' '{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",RT);ORS=RT} 1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/("[^"]*")(.*)/,a){gsub(/ /,"",a[1]); print a[1] a[2]}' file
"serviceblabla1"                   5.456
"serviceblabla2"                   456
```

or FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"| .*' '{gsub(/ /,"",$1); print $1 $2}' file
"serviceblabla1"                   5.456
"serviceblabla2"                   456
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a small loop:

```
sed -r ':a; s/ (.*")/\1/;ta' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sed` command was close but you requested a global substitution which did not give your desired output.

Splitting the `sed` command to address the individual spaces with the same command would have worked.

```
sed 's/ //2;s/ //' $file
```

The will remove the first and second occurence of space.

**Output**

```
"serviceblabla1"                   5.456
"serviceblabla2"                   456
```

This code will only work on the first two spaces.

Comment: What if there re more than two spaces between the ""

Comment: @Jotne I clearly pointed out it will work on only the first two spaces. There are no "what ifs" because if there are more than 2 spaces, this code in its current format will fail. It was pointed out clearly yet you still downvoted?

Comment: Down voted since question is `how delete space in blank only between “ ” with bash`, not how to delete two blank spaces....  And what if line is `test some data "service bla bla2" 5.456` etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`

```
awk '{gsub(/ /,"",$2)}1' OFS=\" FS=\" file
"serviceblabla1"                   5.456
"seryviceblabla2"                   456
```

Split the line by ", replace space in second filed with nothing.